# jQuery not POSTing URL arguments to Jersey service?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jersey

This seems so simple, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I have a Jersey service defined:

```
@POST
public SomeObject createSomeObject(
    @QueryParam("firstParam") String firstParam,
    @QueryParam("secondParam") String secondParam)
{
    // Does stuff, returns the object.
}
```

Now, if I do a simple `curl`, it works fine:

`curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/path/to/service?firstParam=Bleh&secondParam=Blah`

However, the following results in `null` for firstParam and secondParam in the Java:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/service',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        firstParam: 'Bleh',
        secondParam: 'Blah'
    },
    success: doStuff,
    error: eek
});
```

This seems ridiculously straight-forward. I feel they should behave exactly the same. What am I missing? Things I've tried (but don't seem necessary):

- Adding `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to the `ajax` call.
- Adding `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` to the Jersey service.
- Wrapping the data object with `JSON.stringify` (I know I need to do that when `contentType: 'json'`, but shouldn't have to here.

I know I can code the URL parameters myself and stuff 'em in the URL, but that seems inelegant and I shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you send multiple params using POST, you've to do a application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST, that way the params are encoded in the request like:

```
firstParam=Bleh&secondParam=Blah
```

But, to consume theese params you have to annotate the function params like:

```
@POST
public SomeObject createSomeObject(@FormParam("firstParam") String firstParam,
                                   @FormParam("secondParam") String secondParam) {
    // Does stuff, returns the object.
}
```

pay attention in that the annotation is @FormParam instead of @QueryParam

Note that if you do a "normal" POST, your function can only have one param to receive de POSTed data (appart from the params assigned from query string url params)

Comment: Interesting. I never knew about @FormParam. I'll try it when I get home to confirm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 3000,
        // jsonpCallback:"foo",
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);              
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("error!");
        }
    });
```

Above is a jquery request and just as @futuretelematics said we need contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8".
And then add @Consumes( {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED}) in the Jersey service.

```
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes( {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public String execute(@FormParam("stoYardName") String data,
                       @FormParam("domTree") String domTree
                                    ) {
            .........
```

};