# How to access post java method in client

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, restful-url

I need small help,i am new to create rest methods in java but i found it and create a rest methods.I having one class which contains different methods. Here my class

```
@Path("/WebServices ")
public class WebServices {
@POST
@Path("/SourceCreateService")
@Consumes("multipart/related")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String sourceCreateService(@QueryParam("sourceTiltle") String sourceTiltle, @QueryParam("xml") String xml) {
return "name";
}
}

And now i have to access this method in another class,I can use this code to access this method in this class,

try{
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/web/WebServices/SourceCreateService?sourceTiltle=sdds&xml="XML");

URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
// conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

BufferedWriter out =
new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream() ) );
out.write("username=name\r\n");
out.flush();
out.close();
BufferedReader in =
new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream() ) );

}catch(IOException e){
system.out.println(""+e);

}

when  i call this method i got this error,

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL:

I put debugpoint in web service method also,but it not come to that method,it directly throws exception here,so my question is that my webservice methog is right and kindly tell me what is the wrong in my code and my URL
```

Is there any configuration in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Since you are posting form-url-encoding your data, you have to annotate the method param with @FormParam instead of @QueryParam

```
@Path("/WebServices ")
public class WebServices {
    @POST
    @Path("/SourceCreateService")
    @Consumes("multipart/related") @Produces("text/plain")
    public String sourceCreateService(@FormParam("sourceTiltle") String sourceTiltle,     
                                      @QueryParam("xml") String xml) {
            return "name";
    }
}
```

See this question / answer: [jQuery not POSTing URL arguments to Jersey service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704042/jquery-not-posting-url-arguments-to-jersey-service/16779141#16779141)

Comment: thanks for your answer,i tried with FormParam also,that also not working,if i use formparam means,How is it my URL?

Comment: Is there any configuration in web.xml for access the rest methods,Kindly help me

Comment: You have to distinguish between the URL params and the POSTed content in form-url-encoded style.

I mean:<br />
- /SourceCreateService?xml=someXML is a **@QueryParam**
- BUT if you look at what is POSTed (the content POSTed) to the server, you'll see something like:

    sourceTitle=titlevalue 
 
this second one is a **@FormParam**